# Define make variable at rule execution time

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In my GNUmakefile, I would like to have a rule that uses a temporary directory.  For example:

```
out.tar: TMP := $(shell mktemp -d)
        echo hi $(TMP)/hi.txt
        tar -C $(TMP) cf $@ .
        rm -rf $(TMP)
```

As written, the above rule creates the temporary directory at the time that the rule is *parsed*.  This means that, even I don't make out.tar all the time, many temporary directories get created.  I would like to avoid my /tmp being littered with unused temporary directories.

Is there a way to cause the variable to only be defined when the rule is fired, as opposed to whenever it is defined?

My main thought is to dump the mktemp and tar into a shell script but that seems somewhat unsightly.

Answer (score 467, accepted):

In your example, the `TMP` variable is set (and the temporary directory created) whenever the *rules* for `out.tar` are evaluated. In order to create the directory only when `out.tar` is actually fired, you need to move the directory creation down into the steps:

```makefile
out.tar : 
    $(eval TMP := $(shell mktemp -d))
    @echo hi $(TMP)/hi.txt
    tar -C $(TMP) cf $@ .
    rm -rf $(TMP)
```

The [eval](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) function evaluates a string as if it had been typed into the makefile manually. In this case, it sets the `TMP` variable to the result of the `shell` function call.

**edit** (in response to comments):

To create a unique variable, you could do the following:

```makefile
out.tar : 
    $(eval $@_TMP := $(shell mktemp -d))
    @echo hi $($@_TMP)/hi.txt
    tar -C $($@_TMP) cf $@ .
    rm -rf $($@_TMP)
```

This would prepend the name of the target (out.tar, in this case) to the variable, producing a variable with the name `out.tar_TMP`. Hopefully, that is enough to prevent conflicts.

Comment: Be careful with this solution!  `$(eval $@_TMP := $(shell mktemp -d))` will happen when the Makefile is first evaluated *not* in order of the rule procedures.  In other words, `$(eval ...)` happens sooner than you think.  While that might be okay for this example, this method will cause problems for some sequential operations.

Comment: two (off the subject) details: I believe a `>` sign is missing in the echo line `@echo hi > $(TMP)/hi.txt`, or is there a system where that sign is not needed?. And, my tar command did not accept `cf` options without the leading dash `-cf`, but I have seen versions which do accept this.

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon1979 do you know how to overcome those limitations, e.g. eval some variables that should be a result of steps executed earlier in the rule?

Comment: Answering my own question: the workaround for me was creating files during 1st rule execution, and trying to eval them in the first step of 2nd rule.

Comment: Why use `:=` instead of `=` for variable assignment inside a recipe?

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon1979, if you run `make` in this Makefile, it doesn't seem to execute when the Makefile is first evaluated.  Saying it differently, the folder isn't created with `make`, only with `make TEST` as expected. https://gist.github.com/jsign/c7313f359daa99c02bafb222becacad3

Comment: IMO this is not a good solution.  Using `eval` inside a recipe is almost always wrong.  The simple, and portable, way to manage this is to write this all in a single make recipe line.  E.g., `@TMP=$$(mktemp -d) && echo hi > $$TMP/hi.txt && tar -C $$TMP cf $@ . && rm -rf $$TMP` as shown in Brent Bradburn's answer below (although I'm using `&&` instead of `set -e`... I find `set -e` to have some odd corner cases).

Comment: FYI, if you want the declare variable can be accessed in next sequential target, you can do `@$(eval export TMP = : $(shell mktemp -d))`

Answer (score 120):

A relatively easy way of doing this is to write the entire sequence as a shell script.

```
out.tar:
   set -e ;\
   TMP=$$(mktemp -d) ;\
   echo hi $$TMP/hi.txt ;\
   tar -C $$TMP cf $@ . ;\
   rm -rf $$TMP ;\
```

I have consolidated some related tips here: [Multi-line bash commands in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29085684/86967)

Comment: This is definitely the simplest and therefore best answer (avoiding `@` and `eval` and doing the same job). Note that in your output you see `$TMP` (e.g. `tar -C $TMP ...`) although the value is correcty passed to the command.

Comment: This is how it's normally done; I hope people see this answer because in practice nobody goes through all the effort of the accepted one.

Comment: What if you are using shell specific commands ?
In that case shell commands shall be in same shell language than the one calling make, right ? I had seen some makefile with shebang.

Comment: @ptitpion: You may also want [`SHELL := /bin/bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/589276/86967) in your makefile to enable BASH-specific features.

Answer (score 44):

Another possibility is to use separate lines to set up Make variables when a rule fires.

For example, here is a makefile with two rules. If a rule fires, it creates a temp dir and sets TMP to the temp dir name.

```
PHONY = ruleA ruleB display

all: ruleA

ruleA: TMP = $(shell mktemp -d testruleA_XXXX)
ruleA: display

ruleB: TMP = $(shell mktemp -d testruleB_XXXX)
ruleB: display

display:
    echo ${TMP}
```

Running the code produces the expected result:

```
$ ls
Makefile
$ make ruleB
echo testruleB_Y4Ow
testruleB_Y4Ow
$ ls
Makefile  testruleB_Y4Ow
```

Comment: Just as a reminder, GNU make has a syntax for [order-only prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) which may be necessary to complement this approach.

Comment: Be careful with this solution!  `ruleA: TMP = $(shell mktemp -d testruleA_XXXX)` and `ruleB: TMP = $(shell mktemp -d testruleB_XXXX)` will happen when the Makefile is first evaluated.  In other words, `ruleA: TMP = $(shell ...` happens sooner than you think.  While this might work for this particular case, this method will cause problems for some sequential operations.

Comment: That's not my experience - rule-local variables are expanded only when the particular rule is requested (either explicitly or as dependcy)

Comment: This should still work if you do `ruleA: private TMP = ...`. See [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html).

Answer (score 7):

I dislike "Don't" answers, but... don't.

`make`'s variables are global and are supposed to be evaluated during makefile's "parsing" stage, not during execution stage.

In this case, as long as the variable local to a single target, follow [@nobar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29085760/207791) and make it a shell variable.

Target-specific variables, too, are considered harmful by other make implementations: [kati](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/kati/+/master/INTERNALS.md), [Mozilla pymake](https://github.com/mozilla/pymake). Because of them, a target can be built differently depending on if it's built standalone, or as a dependency of a parent target with a target-specific variable. **And you won't know which way it was**, because you don't know what is already built.

Comment: local variables would be useful even if they are, well, truly local, i.e. they are not visible downwards to the rules that get executed under us.

Comment: @AttilaLendvai at the time of writing the answer, I didn't know [you can make target-specific variable private](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suppressing-Inheritance.html). This surely makes them more safe, but I would still discourage their usage.