# Makefile environment based on targets

Tags: makefile

This code doesn't work:

```
$ cat Makefile
dev:
        AWS_PROFILE=foobar-$@ echo $$AWS_PROFILE

demo:
        AWS_PROFILE=foobar-$@ echo $$AWS_PROFILE
```

Based on my target, I want the AWS_PROFILE correctly setup for the commands in the target. How does one achieve this with `GNU Make 4.2.1`?

Comment: Did you try to add a semi-colon before the `echo` command?

Comment: That works! but what about next lines, or do the next commands need to be ; seperated on one long line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711963/change-makefile-variable-value-inside-the-target-body) question.

Comment: @AmeyaVS no, it's not a question about make variables

Comment: @hendry you can use line continuation (`\`) to break long lines. See my answer for an example.

Comment: `what about next lines` You can use [.ONESHELL](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add a semi-colon before the `echo` command:

```
dev:
    AWS_PROFILE=foobar-$@; echo $$AWS_PROFILE
```

Each line of a recipe is sent to a different shell. So, if you want to propagate shell variables you must define and use them on the same line, in the same shell list. You could also use `&&` or `||` to join your individual shell commands.

Note that, for better readability, you can use the line continuation:

```
dev:
    AWS_PROFILE=foobar-$@; \
    echo $$AWS_PROFILE
```