# Makefile dynamic variables as prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Perhaps it's something that I'm getting wrong. Basically my task is to use `make` to automate a build, deploy, starting, stopping of different services. 
One of the things that I'm trying to do is to have a variable as a target prerequisite, however that variable has to be changed in another target.

Here's a basic sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
IMAGE_COUNT=-1

count_images:
    $(eval IMAGE_COUNT=5)

_should_build: $(if $(findstring $(IMAGE_COUNT),0), build,)

build:
    ...some procedure to build...

start: _should_build
    ...some procedure to start a service...
```

Obviously the `$(IMAGE_COUNT)` in `_should_build` check will stay as -1, but what I want is to have the `$(IMAGE_COUNT)` become a 5 during the prerequisite check. A thing to note is that I cannot place the counting of images outside the `count_images` target.
Does anyone know if this is possible at all?

Comment: Is the usage of a file possible ? Because I don't think it's possible with a single variable, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711963/change-makefile-variable-value-inside-the-target-body/2714110)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Perhaps it's something that I'm getting wrong.

That "something" is called an evaluation order.

> One of the things that I'm trying to do is to have a variable as a target prerequisite, however that variable has to be changed in *another target*.

Not *a target*, but *a recipe*. The recipes are preprocessed before execution. While the prerequisites are preprocessed on the first pass. In fact, changing the value of a make's variable inside a recipe in 90% of cases is a mistake. (Also remember that all preprocessing is done before feeding the recipe to the shell).

> Does anyone know if this is possible at all?

Everything is possible, of course, but not this way.

> A thing to note is that I cannot place the counting of images outside the count_images target.

Most probably, you can.

Anyway, the point is that some shell script (a recipe, or a part of a recipe) should return a number. However, such return values cannot be stored in a make's variable. Re-think your design and find another way for communication between your targets.