# Can't assign variable inside recipe

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How do I make this work? It errors out with "make: somevariable: Command not found"

```
sometarget:
    somevariable = somevalue
```

Full example:

```
CXXFLAGS = -I/usr/include/test -shared -fPIC

OBJ = main.o Server.o

blabla : $(OBJ) 
ifeq ($(argsexec),true) 
    # Creates an executable
    CXXFLAGS = -I/usr/include/test
    $(CXX) -o blabla $(OBJ) $(CXXFLAGS) 
else 
    # Creates a library
    DESTDIR = /home/pc
    $(CXX) -o blabla $(OBJ) $(CXXFLAGS) 
    ./bn.sh
endif
```

Comment: Did u find a better solution?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909188/define-make-variable-at-rule-execution-time

Comment: Pritesh: I now use the tup buildsystem for all my c/c++ projects. http://gittup.org/tup/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define make variable at rule execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909188/define-make-variable-at-rule-execution-time)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I found a solution using [the `eval` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html):

```
$(eval variablename=whatever)
```

This works :)

(although I may now try to find an easier build system ;))

Thanks everyone for reading and also of course @eriktous for writing!

Answer (score 4):

If you write it like you did, the assignment will be executed as a shell command, which gives the error you got.

I would try organising it something like this:

```
CXXFLAGS = -I/usr/include/test
ifneq ($(argsexec),true) 
  CXXFLAGS += -shared -fPIC
  DESTDIR = /home/pc
endif

OBJ = main.o Server.o

blabla : $(OBJ) 
    $(CXX) -o blabla $(OBJ) $(CXXFLAGS) 
ifneq ($(argsexec),true) 
    ./bn.sh
endif
```

This should do what you want, although I'm not quite happy with using the `ifneq` construct twice. I'd have to think harder to come up with something that avoids that.