# How to set Makefile variable and make on Mac OS X?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How do I write a Makefile that is able to store a dynamic value inside a static variable that can be reused throughout the `make` command? On Mac OS X, when I run `make` I have a problem where I can't set variables following instructions in [the GNU docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html#Setting).

#### Setting vars doesn't work as expected

A simple Makefile looks like this.

```
announce:
        starttime := `date`
        echo The time is now $(starttime)
```

When I run `make announce` I get the following error.

```
/bin/sh: starttime: command not found
make: *** [announce] Error 127
```

#### `eval` workaround tried

I've tried the solution offered in [a previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519234/cant-assign-variable-inside-recipe), to use `$(eval myvar = "some value or expr")`. However, what I found is that this approach makes the variable dynamically calculated every time it's used. So, given the Makefile below, I expect the same time to be printed twice.

```
announce:
        $(eval starttime = `date`)
        echo The time is now $(starttime)
        sleep 3
        echo The time is now $(starttime)
```

But in reality, two different times will be printed instead of one consistent time.

```
Martys-MacBook-Air:express-babel-eb marty$ make announce
echo The time is now `date`
The time is now Thu Nov 3 18:27:39 EDT 2016
sleep 3
echo The time is now `date`
The time is now Thu Nov 3 18:27:43 EDT 2016
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, [reading more into the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors) and experimenting, I found that [`shell`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html#Shell-Function) does what I want it to do. The following Makefile can be used to echo the same timestamped value twice, as desired.

```
githash := $(shell git rev-parse --short HEAD)
timestamp := $(shell date +%s)
envname := markable-$(githash)-$(timestamp)

announce:
        echo $(envname)
        sleep 3
        echo $(envname)
```