# GNU Make: requested target

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

Is there any GNU Make special variable for knowing which target was the one sent by the user in the command line call? To achieve something like (it is just an example):

```
// makefile
ifeq ($(USER_TARGET),"plain")
CXXFLAGS += -O0
else
CXXFLAGS += -O3
endif

plain:
    // do something using CXXFLAGS

all:
    // other rule using CXXFLAGS
```

It's important that, the `USER_TARGET` variable (which can be an special GNU Make variable, or a custom variable which value was set by some special GNU Make function returning the user target), contains the original target specified by the user in a call like:

```
$ make plain
```

and not the value in any step of the dependency tree. In other words, the `USER_TARGET` must not change during the building dependence chain, because, if I'm not wrong, the value of `USER_TARGET` will be evaluated when it is used by the first time, and than can happen in any point of the document, so, I want to be sure the current step of building chain don't change the value of `USER_TARGET`.

I don't know if I have been clear enough or if it is was overexplained.

If there is no built-in mechanism for that in GNU Make, any `$(shell command)` trick is welcome as well.

Comment: Perhaps this would work for you? [Can't assign a variable inside a recipe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519234/cant-assign-variable-inside-recipe).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I recently saw a makefile with `debug: clean` `@make CFLAGS='${DEBUG_CFLAGS}'`

Comment: Just take care, multiple targets could be specified eg `make -f Makefile build test` could be used to call both the build and test targets

Comment: @mjs That's right, good point. I haven't thought about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `MAKECMDGOALS` variable, [described here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html).