# evaluating a variable in makefile recipe to find command

Tags: bash, makefile

I have this line of bash script, which I'm trying to add to a makefile:

```
 go_files=$(find . -name "*.go" -not -path "*/test1/*" -not -path "*/test2/*")
```

I've already tried these:
(due to [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6520603/2762170))

```
for_on_go:
    $(eval p := $(find . -name "*.go" -not -path "*/test1/*" -not -path "*/test2/*"))
    @echo $(p)
```

and

```
for_on_go:
    protos=$(find . -name "*.go" -not -path "*/test1/*" -not -path "*/test2/*"); \
    echo $$protos; \
```

which both are not working or echoing the correct result. I also want to loop over these results after this.

Comment: Each line in a makefile recipe executes in its own sub-shell. So if you succeed in assigning a value to a *shell* variable, that variable will not survive to the next line in the recipe. You can assign a value to a *Make* variable, but that will not be specific to a rule. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: There are many issues with what you're trying to do as Beta points out.  However, the basic fundamental problem you have is that `$` is a special character in makefiles.  So if you want to use the literal `$` in your recipes you need to escape it, using `$$` instead.  So to use shell command replacement like `$(find ...)` you have to write it as `$$(find ...)`.  Or else go back to the traditional syntax with backquotes: `\`find ...\``

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have to run `find` within a rule, you can just do it like so (using `$(shell...)` for running a command, and `$(...)` for multi-characters variables

```
protos=$(shell find . -name "*.go" -not -path "*/test1/*" -not -path "*/test2/*")

for_on_go:
    echo $(protos)
```