# Make commands with variables

Tags: bash, makefile

I've been learning `make` and am struggling to figure something out. I have some rules with this general structure.

```
FILE = "myfile.txt"

test :
    YOUR = $(subst my,your,$(FILE));\
    cat $(FILE) $(YOUR)
```

I would expect the end result to be running the command:

```
cat myfile.txt yourfile.txt
```

Instead I get the following...

```
YOUR = "yourfile.txt";\
    cat "myfile.txt" 
/bin/sh: YOUR: command not found
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

If instead of using the `subst` function, I just do `YOUR="yourfile"` in the `makefile`, everything looks fine. Any suggestions or have I missed something pretty fundamental? I should add that I'm using tabs and not spaces to start the lines for the commands within the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FILE = "myfile.txt"

test :
    $(eval YOUR = $(subst my,your,$(FILE)))
    cp $(FILE) $(YOUR)
```

You have to use the `eval` function in the recipe ([Define make variable at rule execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909188/define-make-variable-at-rule-execution-time))

Comment: Thanks - this does it. In the more complex example test would be something like $(test) and I'd need to do a subst on the $@ valiable and then pass the result to a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between what `make` executes and what the shell executes.  Your line with `YOUR =` starts with a tab and is part of the actions of a rule, so it is executed by the shell, which can't find a program `YOUR` to execute with some arguments.

Place the expansion outside the rule:

```
YOUR = $(subst my,your,$(FILE))

test:
    cat $(FILE) $(YOUR)
```

Note that shell assignments require no space around the equals sign, and use `${}` rather than `$()` to reference variables: `YOUR=${FILE/my/your}` in Bash (and if written in a `make` rule, you'd need `$$` in place of `$` so that the shell sees a single dollar sign and `make` does not try the variable expansion that it doesn't understand).  The shell uses `$()` to execute the command contained within, and the result is often captured in a variable: `YOUR=$(echo "${FILE}" | sed 's/my/your/')`.

Comment: you are right, but in that case you can use it just echo "$file"

Comment: @BallPython `echo "$file"` in a make recipe will not work correctly... unless you are expecting make to expand an `$f` variable and have `echo` spit out `<value-of-f>ile`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the variable in the shell recipe and not in the make context then you don't need to bother playing with eval (which are hoisted) and can just assign to shell variables instead.

For example:

```
FILE = "myfile.txt"

test :
    YOUR='$(subst my,your,$(FILE))';\
    cat $(FILE) "$${YOUR}"
```