# What is $(NOOP) typically used for in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

**In a Makefile, what is $(NOOP) typically used for?**

I see in one particular Makefile, `NOOP` is set to `/bin/sh -c true`  and it is used in many rules such as this one:

```
all: pure_all
    $(NOECHO) $(NOOP)
```

How is this better/different than

```
all: pure_all
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is likely a verbose (and less efficient, though perhaps more portable I don't know) attempt at an [Empty Recipe](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Empty-Recipes).

Specifically, without marking a recipe as [`.PHONY`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) or otherwise giving them a recipe as in the question a target will be subject to [Implicit Rule Search](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rule-Search).

This search can be slow at times and can do things that aren't desirable.

<sup>Aside: The comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31482128/258523) cover the topic of `.PHONY` rules and their `FORCE` equivalents fairly well I think (though in a round-about fashion as that wasn't the point).</sup>