# GNU Make: how to make a rule that has multiple triggers run once in parallel mode?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
A/a A/b A/c ... A/n:
  ./do-something.sh # creates all n-files in one run
```

And:

```
all: A/a A/b A/c ... A/n
```

plays nice in a single threaded `make`, but when I run `make -j 16`, for example, sixteen independent runs of `./do-something.sh` get spawned.

Is there a makish way to inhibit that, and tell make that the rule should be run one time?

Comment: Do you mean *14* independent runs get scheduled?  Because that's what should happen, even in single-processing mode.  Remember that `make` is *target*-centric, not *rule*-centric.  Each target is built at most once, but if the same rule is applicable for building multiple targets then that rule may run more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GNU make if you can structure your rule as a pattern rule, then it behaves this way (one invocation creates all targets) [automatically](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html) and always has.

If you can't structure your rule as a pattern rule (the targets don't have any common substrings) then you can either use a kludge such as mentioned by Christopher, except they forgot the `touch` command and that there should be a no-op command for the real targets:

```
craft-A:
       ./do-something.sh A
       @touch $@

A/a A/b A/... A/inf: craft-A ;
```

Or you can move to GNU make 4.3 which supports the `&:` [grouped target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Targets.html) capability, and write:

```
A/a A/b A/c ... A/n &:
        ./do-something.sh # creates all n-files in one run
```

Comment: yes, this is what I am calling a "kludge", and have been doing things this way for years.  My hope one day is that I don't have all this make dandruff lying around in my automation nodes.

Comment: See my final paragraph: "one day" is today... assuming you have a new-enough version of GNU make.

Comment: my bad.  should have read it completely. was ready for a flaming.  Here is a link to an explanation of the no-op command: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662514/what-is-noop-typically-used-for-in-makefile

Answer (score 1):

Well, as always, `make` yields to some cleverness, and there is a reason this was not implemented:

```
craft-A:
  ./do-something.sh A
A/a A/b A/... A/inf: craft-A

all: A/... 

$: make -j 100 all
```

Works.  But, the can is kicked down the road: the rule is not idempotent.  So it is *an* answer, but it seems to be very hard to make it idempotent without a kludge.