# Make return error 127

Tags: filter, makefile, subst

Am trying to match specific string after doing subst on a variable ; substitution is ok but while trying to match make returns error 127.

Does anyone know what's going on here ? why make should return error ?

> $> make -f strsearch.mk
>
> CODE : BBROY_OF_GREAT_BRITAIN_HAD_A_GREAT_WIFE
>
> MORSE =  BBROY OF GREAT BRITAIN HAD A GREAT WIFE
>
> **make: MORSE: Command not found
>
> make: *** [search_new] Error 127**

Here is the snippet of makefile:

`VAR1 := BBROY_OF_GREAT_BRITAIN_HAD_A_GREAT_WIFE`

`search_new:
        @echo CODE : $(VAR1)
        MORSE = $(subst _, , $(VAR1))
        @echo word count : ($words $(MORSE))
        @echo After substitution Britain matches: $(filter %BRITAIN%, $(MORSE))`

Comment: It's a valid and good question with good description (but bad title). I don't quite understand the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable declaration is in the wrong place or form:

The form you use is for global assignment and cannot be inside a target block.

- Either make it a global variable outside a target block
- Or use the shell and eval to set the variable value. See the accepted answer for how to approach this issue: [Define make variable at rule execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909188/define-make-variable-at-rule-execution-time)
- A 3rd option is to define the variable as a sort-of prerequisite which is then assigned at the time the dependencies are evaluated.

Comment: Thanks @planetmaker, eval option worked ; was able to overcome the error reported by make.