# Pass variable to child make only if defined

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I can pass a variable to child make using `make -C VAR=$(VAR) target` (preferring this to `export` because the variable is only meaningful for a single target). However, it appears that if `VAR` variable isn't defined in parent, child gets an empty string (it has `VAR ?= ...`, and the value of `VAR` is empty). How can I avoid this?

It looks like a variation on [Define make variable at rule execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909188/define-make-variable-at-rule-execution-time) should work for my specific usecase, but it requires the parent Makefile to know child's default value, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always use `$(MAKE)` when invoking sub-makes, never `make` explicitly.  Also you're missing a directory after the `-C` in your examples.

What about something like:

```
$(MAKE) $(if $(VAR),VAR=$(VAR))
```