# Define variables in one build rule and use it in other build rules

Tags: makefile

The setup is a Makefile with the following content (inspired by the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20714468/185475):

```
prerule: VALUE = Hello
prerule: 
    @echo "in prerule"
    @echo ${VALUE}

record: prerule
    @echo "in record"
    @echo ${VALUE}
```

I would like to define a variable in one rule, which is used as a prerequisite for a different rule (or actual a set of rules).
With the current setup, the following output is generated:

```
$ make record 
in prerule
Hello
in record

$
```

What I would like to have as output is the following:

```
$ make record 
in prerule
Hello
in record
Hello
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add:

```
$(eval VALUE := $(VALUE))
```

to the recipe of `prerule` but be warned that it will set the `VALUE` variable globally as soon as the `prerule` recipe is executed. Not just for the context of the `record` rule.

Demo:

```
$ cat Makefile
prerule: VALUE = Hello
prerule: 
    @echo "VALUE = $(VALUE) in $@"
    $(eval VALUE := $(VALUE))

record: prerule
    @echo "VALUE = $(VALUE) in $@"

foobar: 
    @echo "VALUE = $(VALUE) in $@"
$ make foobar
VALUE =  in foobar
$ make foobar record
VALUE =  in foobar
VALUE = Hello in prerule
VALUE = Hello in record
$ make record foobar
VALUE = Hello in prerule
VALUE = Hello in foobar
VALUE = Hello in record
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thanks!