# How to only print the variable name itself as part of the recipes?

Tags: makefile

Example:

```
var1 = x

dep : $(var1)
     echo ($^ -> $@)
```

This will show x -> dep, but what I really want to show is var1 -> dep.

I basically want to sprinkle this echo all over the rules so I can make sense of a dependency graph. Nothing else worked.

Comment: You can't, I am afraid: make expands the list of prerequisites and there is no way to recover its unexpanded form in the recipe.

Comment: Is there at least a way to print out the file and line number this echo is called from?

Comment: You can use the `$(warning ...)` function to show filename/linenumber information.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to work in my environment your makefile needs two slight modifications: replace the parentheses in `echo` with quotes, and add a rule for `x`, to give:

```
var1 = x

dep: $(var1)
    echo "$^ -> $@"

x:
```

There appears to be no method to recover the unexpanded form of a variable name in a recipe.  My suggested solution/work-around is twofold: cache the variable name in another variable, and as per MadScientist's comment use `$(warning ...)`. For example, the makefile:

```
var1 = x

dep: var1_=var1
dep: $(var1)
    @echo "$^ -> $@"
    @echo "$(var1_) -> $@"
    $(warning "Info: Using $^ to build $@")
    $(warning "Info: Using $(var1) to build $@")
    $(warning "Info: Using $(var1_) to build $@")
    $(warning "Info: Using $($(var1_)) to build $@")

x:
```

will give:

```
Makefile:7: "Info: Using x to build dep"
Makefile:8: "Info: Using x to build dep"
Makefile:9: "Info: Using var1 to build dep"
Makefile:10: "Info: Using x to build dep"
x -> dep
var1 -> dep
```

The `var1_` variable needs to be defined on a *separate* line (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20714468/318716), which doesn't appear to be well-documented. And the order of the output is interesting.

Edit: A more simple variant of this idea is to replace:

```
var1 = x

dep: var1_=var1
```

with just:

```
var1 = x
var1_ = var1
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Joseph. I am sure there are ways to do what I am asking by adding more code. But my main point was to do that using only one statement. We have a huge complex makefile system with many parts and files sprinkled. I want to understand the dependencies better without adding too much code. I just wanted to paste same statement every where there is a recipe and be done with it.