# Getting `make install` to source your bash_completion

Tags: bash, autocomplete, makefile

This is the install part of my Makefile:

```
install:
    for e in $(EXEC); do \
        sudo cp --remove-destination ${CURDIR}/$$e /usr/local/bin; done
    sudo cp ${CURDIR}/bin/stage2.d /etc/bash_completion.d/stage2
    . /etc/bash_completion
```

Where "stage2" is the name of my executable.

The last line is what provides the issue. After adding a file into `bash_completion.d` directory I want to `source` the `bash_completion`. But calling `source` or `.` yields:

```
. /etc/bash_completion
/etc/bash_completion: 32: [[: not found
/etc/bash_completion: 38: [[: not found
/etc/bash_completion: 50: Bad substitution
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Comment: which version of bash are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make uses `/bin/sh` by default.  you have to force it to use bash since `[[` is not supported by normal `sh`.

gnu make lets you set `SHELL` variable [in the makefile] to force it to use bash.  So you would need to add a line

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

at the top of your makefile

Comment: in combination with : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589276/how-can-i-use-bash-syntax-in-makefile-targets

Comment: colon is not necessary.  try it out without the colon  (in this case both are acceptable)

Comment: let me be more specific: the := is an immediate evaluation [its processed at that spot] whereas the = is deferred [expansion occurs when it is used -- akin to C macro]

Comment: Sourcing bash completion stuff into a non-interactive shell still makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

I see two issues:

1. Using `sudo` in a `Makefile` rule is a bad idea. Avoid that, and call `sudo make install` instead.
2. Why would you want to source the `bash_completion` file in the non-interactive shell which is the make rule? It makes no sense.

As to solving them:

```
install:
    $(INSTALL) -m 0755 -d $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)
    $(INSTALL) -m 0755 -p $(EXEC) $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/
    $(INSTALL) -m 0755 -d $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/bash_completion.d
    $(INSTALL) -m 0644 -p ${CURDIR}/bin/stage2.d $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/bash_completion.d/stage2
```

for the make rule part and

```
sudo make install && . /etc/bash_completion.d/stage2
```

for the actual running of that command. You will want to document the latter in a README, or in a line which the `install:` target prints when finished.

Comment: `$(INSTALL)` is the complicated/flexible way commonly used to call `install(1)` from a `Makefile`. Add a line `INSTALL = install` at the beginning of your `Makefile` to provide a default.