# Using bash variables in Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, environment-variables, timing

I want to use the bash timing variables in my makefile
for example in my terminal I can do this and it works

```
 MY_TIME=$SECONDS 
 echo $MY_TIME
```

but when I write this on my makefile it does not work

how can I use these two lines in my make file?

this is what I'm doing

```
.PHONY: myProg
myProg:
      MY_TIME=$SECONDS 
      echo $MY_TIME
```

After Etan Reisner' answer

This is what I have now

```
.PHONY: myProg
 myProg:
        MY_TIME= date; echo $MY_TIME
```

but the result of my echo is an empty line, it does not look like it is storing the date

Comment: Where are you putting that in your makefile? That's obviously not a valid make variable. It will likely work in a recipe if you set make up to use `bash` as the shell (as opposed to the default of `/bin/sh`).

Comment: Each line runs in a separate shell, so no.

Comment: @EtanReisner How do I do that? I updated my question.

Comment: `MY_TIME= date` is running the `date` command with an environment variable named `MY_TIME` that contains an empty string. You need `MY_TIME=$(date)` to capture the output from `date` in the `MY_TIME` variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default make uses `/bin/sh` as the shell which executes recipe lines.

Presumably `/bin/sh` doesn't support the `SECONDS` variable.

You can tell make to use a different shell by assigning a value to the `SHELL` variable (i.e. `SHELL := /bin/bash`).

Doing that will make `SECONDS` available but will still not allow you to carry a variable value between recipe lines as each recipe line is run in its own shell.

So to do what you want you would need to write both of those lines on one line or continue the line over the newline.

```
.PHONY: myProg
myProg:
      MY_TIME=$SECONDS; echo $MY_TIME
```

or

```
.PHONY: myProg
myProg:
      MY_TIME=$SECONDS; \
      echo $MY_TIME
```

That being said you would almost certainly be better off *not* doing this and instead using something like `date` invoked at the start/end of the recipe or `time` invoked *on* the command to be timed directly instead.

```
.PHONY: myProg
myProg:
      date
      # Do something
      date
```

or

```
.PHONY: myProg
myProg:
      time some_command
```

Comment: Is there a way to store the output of date in a variable to use it later?

Comment: Only with the line-continuation version of things. Or if you have a new enough version of make and choose to use [.ONESHELL](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002eONESHELL).

Comment: You can apparently also set a `make` variable with `$(eval LOL := $(shell echo $$RANDOM))` (SECONDS is pointless since it's always 0 on startup). On the next line, you can then `echo $(LOL)` to write out the value.

Comment: @thatotherguy No need for `$(eval ...)` on that if that's in a normal make context. You'd need that in macros and on recipe lines though. And yes, `SECONDS` is going to be near-to-useless in any non-continuation scenario.

Comment: @EtanReisner I updated the result that I'm getting, it is still not storing the date

Comment: @EtanReisner It's needed to set it during processing of a make rule (instead of top level), which I think was the point.

Comment: Thanks @EtanReisner, i found an easier solution which using time. But as you said I needed to set up the make to use the bash. Thanks!

Comment: Your first example doesn't work for me. ```$ make whatever-stag                                                               
MYVAR=stag; echo YVAR                                                                                                   
YVAR    ```

Comment: Check this to see how to set SHELL at global level in makefile or target specific: https://stackoverflow.com/a/589300/1097444

Answer (score 22):

the dollar sign (`$MY_TIME`) refers to *make variables*, which are not the same as *bash variables*.

To access a *bash variable* you must escape the dollar using the double dollar notation (`$$MY_TIME`).

```
.PHONY: myProg
myProg:
  MY_TIME=$$SECONDS ; echo $$MY_TIME
```

As already mentioned in [Etan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29500862/1029516) you can't split the code into multiple lines (unless you are using the backslash) since each command executes in a different subshell, making variables inaccessible to other lines.

In the following example the value of `SECONDS` will be always `0`, since it get reset by the spawn of the shell for the second line.

```
.PHONY: myProg
myProg:      # WRONG
  MY_TIME=$$SECONDS
  echo $$MY_TIME
```

Answer (score -2):

```
PROGRAM_NAME = myLittleProgram

...

$(PROGRAM_NAME) : myLittleProgram.o
```

I know the above works, as it is in my own makefile (program names and object names changed to protect the innocent).

---

"Variable references can be used in any context: targets, dependencies, commands, most directives, and new variable values. Here is an example of a common case, where a variable holds the names of all the object files in a program:"

```
objects = program.o foo.o utils.o
program : $(objects)
    cc -o program $(objects)

$(objects) : defs.h
```

`http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/make_6.html`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question that was asked and doesn't even appear to attempt to address it.