# Invoking bash commands in makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

Inside of a `makefile`, I'm trying to check if fileA was modified more recently than fileB. Using a few prior posts ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589276/how-can-i-use-bash-syntax-in-makefile-targets) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash)) as references, I've come up with this as an attempt to store the time since last file modification as a variable:

(I'd rather this be in a function outside of a `make` recipe, but one step at a time.)

```
    .PHONY: all clean

    all      : (stuff happens here)

    radio    :
              BASE_MOD_TIME="$( expr $(date +%s) - $(date +%s -r src/radio_interface/profile_init.c) )"
              @echo "$(BASE_MOD_TIME)"
```

I thought that I would be assigning the output of the `expr` command to a variable, `BASE_MOD_TIME`, but the output is:

```
    bash-4.1$
    BASE_MOD_TIME=""
    echo ""
```

What am I doing wrong here? Simple attempts to save the output of `ls -l` also didn't work like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make variables are normally global, and you don't normally set make variables in a recipe.  A recipe is simply a list of commands to be executed by a shell, and so what looks like a variable assignment in a recipe is a shell variable assignment.

However, each line in a `make` recipe is run in its own shell subprocess. So a variable set in one line won't be visible in another line; they are not persistent. That makes setting shell variables in recipes less useful. [Note 1]

But you can combine multiple lines of a recipe into a single shell command using the backslash escape at the end of the line, and remembering to terminate the individual commands with semicolons (or, better, link them with `&&`), because the backslash-escaped newline will not be passed to the shell. Also, don't forget to escape the `$` characters so they will be passed to the shell, rather than being interpreted by `make`.

So you could do the following:

```
radio:
    @BASE_MOD_TIME="$$( expr $$(date +%s) - $$(date +%s -r src/radio_interface/profile_init.c) )"; \
    echo "$$BASE_MOD_TIME"; \
    # More commands in the same subprocess
```

But that gets quite awkward if there are more than a couple of commands, and a better solution is usually to write a shell script and invoke it from the recipe (although that means that the Makefile is no longer self-contained.)

Gnu make provides two ways to set make variables in a recipe:

#### 1. Target-specific variables.

You can create a target-specific variable (which is not exactly local to the target) by adding a line like:

```
target: var := value
```

To set the variable from a shell command, use the `shell` function:

```
target: var := $(shell ....)
```

This variable will be available in the target recipe *and all dependencies triggered by the target*. Note that a dependency is only evaluated once, so if it could be triggered by a different target, the target-specific variable might or might not be available in the dependency, depending on the order in which `make` resolves dependencies.

#### 2. Using the `eval` function

Since the expansion of recipes is always deferred, you can use the `eval` function inside a recipe to defer the assignment of a make variable. The `eval` function can be placed pretty well anywhere in a recipe because its value is the empty string. However, `eval`ing a variable assignment makes the variable assignment global; it will be visible throughout the makefile, but its value in other recipes will depend, again, on the order in which make evaluates recipes, which is not necessarily predictable.

For example:

```
radio:
    $(eval var = $(shell ...))
```

---

#### Notes:

1. You can change this behaviour using the `.ONESHELL:` pseudo-target, but that will apply to the entire Makefile; there is no way to mark a single recipe as being executed in a single subprocess. Since changing the behaviour can break recipes in unexpected ways, I don't usually recommend this feature.

Comment: "You can't set a make variable in a recipe": actually you can with something like `$(eval FOO := bar)`. It has to begin with a tab though, otherwise it will be set at parsing time. Also there's `.ONESHELL`.

Comment: @rici, I tried your solution here but was still unable to capture the output of the `expr` command for whatever reason. After trying a few things to fix it, I settled on a separate `bash` script that I invoke in the `make` recipe. I posted more details in an answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Allen: yes, the bash script is probably the best solution. I should have suggested it. You can certainly capture the output in a shell variable but as I said the variable is local to the command, not the recipe. So the entire recipe would need to be a single command-line, which requires backslash-escaping all tje line endings and semicolon-terminating all the commands. I probably should have been clearer.

Comment: @andrea: I'm always reluctant to suggest `.ONESHELL` because its effect is global, which csn wreak havoc.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with this?

```
fileB: fileA
    @echo $< was modified more recently than $@
```

Comment: This seems to just be echoing that fileB was modified more recently. I was looking to test if that was the case, then do stuff if so.

Comment: Make already does that; it's what it does. A dependency on the file whose modification time you are interested in is all it takes.

Comment: @tripleee: the files of interest were python files, so they do not get compiled.

Comment: I don't see how that's pertinent. If you have a recipe with a dependency `A: B` then it will execute if B is newer than A, or if A is missing, when you `make A`, and otherwise, Make will conclude that nothing needs to be done. If this is not what you want, your question is unclear.

Comment: Just to be painfully clear, you'd replace the `echo` with the commands you actually want to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of forcing the `makefile` to do all of the heavy lifting via some `bash` commands, I just called a separate `bash` script. This provided a lot more clarity for a newbie to `bash` scripting like myself since I didn't have to worry about escaping the current shell being used by `make`.

Final solution:

```
    .PHONY: all clean

    all      : (stuff happens here)

    radio    :
            ./radio_init_check.sh
            $(MKDIR_P) $(OBJDIR)
            make $(radio_10)
```

with `radio_init_check.sh` being my sew script.

Comment: this doesn't work in a makefile. ./.sh won't run