# Why won't bash support !(...) patterns when executed via make (w/ SHELL:=/bin/bash)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile

I have a problem running a line of code in my Makefile that runs well in `/bin/bash`. I know that Make runs in `/bin/sh` so I have [solved that problem with this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589300/7553648) by declaring to Make that I want it to run in Bash. However, even though I run Make in Bash I still cant get this line to work, even tough it works in Bash just fine.

Why does Bash throw an error when running `rm -f !(2).txt` in the Makefile but not when executed out in its shell?

> **EDIT:** I seek to delete all files with a certain file extension except one of those files. The command `rm -f !(2).txt` [does just that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/217208/7553648) in my bash terminal but not in Make.
>
> **EDIT:** When running `rm -f !(2).txt` "normally" in the terminal with Bash (terminal returned `bash` when issuing command `echo "$0"`) it works just fine but whey I run `/bin/bash -c 'rm -f !(2).txt'` I get the same error as in the Makefile.

## Makefile

```sh
all: clean

clean: SHELL:=/bin/bash
clean:
    rm -f !(2).txt
```

## Running command in Bash

```sh
 $ ls
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt  4.txt  Makefile    # Directory has all text files
 $ rm -f !(2).txt                       # Remove all text files but 2.txt
 $ ls
2.txt  Makefile                         # Only 2.txt is not removed
```

## Running command in Bash through Makefile

```sh
 $ ls                                   # Directory has all text files
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt  4.txt  Makefile
 $ make clean                           # Running make 
rm -f !(2).txt
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `rm -f !(2).txt'
make: *** [clean] Error 1
```

Comment: You need to `shopt -s extglob`, too.

Comment: If I run your command from the shell, it fails the same way as it does when invoked from make: `/bin/bash -c 'echo !(2).txt'` -> `/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token '('`

Comment: @MadScientist Weird. Running it the way you did ended in the same error. However, running it just in my terminal gives me the expected result. My terminal returns `bash` when I run `echo "$0"` so what can be the hickup?

Comment: The issue was explained below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the `extglob` shell option in order to make it work. In GNU make, it can be achieved by

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
.SHELLFLAGS := -O extglob -c
```

---

**Edit by question author**

The example with the two rows of code above did not work for me but as [this fellow found out](https://superuser.com/questions/619849/bash-extended-globbing-inside-a-makefile#comment769890_619851), there seems to be a different solution depending on versions.

> Hmm. For some reason the `.SHELLFLAGS` didn't work for me, but putting the flags directly in `SHELL=/bin/bash -O extglob -c` did. [...] – Timothy Jones

The example [@choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba) uses works in Make 4.0 but did not work for me since I have Make 3.81. However, here is my solution:

```
all: clean

clean: SHELL=/bin/bash -O extglob -c
clean:
    rm -f !(2).txt
```

Comment: Ok but I still get an error. This is my Makefile now...

    `clean: SHELL:=/bin/bash <new line>    clean: .SHELLFLAGS := -O extglob -c <new line>    clean: <new line>     rm -f !(2).txt`

...and I get the same error.

Comment: @PetterKarkea: It works for me. What version of Make and bash do you run?

Comment: Bash 4.3.11(1)-release, GNU Make 3.81

Comment: I have slightly more recent ones, but I don't see why it should matter (4.2.53(1), 4.0).

Comment: Ah! Solved the problem. I had to write it like this: `SHELL=/bin/bash -O extglob -c`. I found the answer [here](http://superuser.com/questions/619849/bash-extended-globbing-inside-a-makefile#comment769890_619851).

Comment: Seems like the version difference was important, after all :)

Comment: The `.SHELLFLAGS` variable was added in GNU make 3.82.  You can check the NEWS file to see what features were added in which releases: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS

Answer (score 0):

Make has no idea what "!(2).txt" means, if you really must use this construct, then use the $(shell) function:

```
%(shell rm -f !(2).txt)
```

Personally, I would change your file naming scheme or build the file names you want to delete in a make variable.

Comment: `!(2).txt` doesn't mean anything to a default bash either, so it won't work in `%(shell ...)` without preparation described in choroba's answer.