# Using bash arithmetic expansion in GNU makefile

Tags: bash, gnu-make

I would like to use `bash`'s arithmetic expansion for binary operations in a Makefile (GNU make + bash on Debian). These are not covered by `expr`. I need this in a Makefile:

```
$ x=$(( 255 & 2#11110000)); echo $x
240
```

Things that don't work:

```
$ cat Makefile 
all: a b

a: # $ interpreted by make
    x=$(( 255 & 2#11110000)); echo $$x

b: # escaped $
    x=$$(( 255 & 2#11110000)); echo $$x
```

`(a)` obviously doesn't work, and `(b)` doesn't either:

```
$ make b
x=$(( 255 & 2#11110000)); echo $x
/bin/sh: 1: arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: " 255 & 2#11110000"
```

What's a possible way? Generous amounts of quoting, backticking and escaping also yielded no results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use Bash syntax in Makefile targets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589276/how-can-i-use-bash-syntax-in-makefile-targets)

Comment: Thank you Kamil, yes, that is closely related, but was just too general so it didn't pop up on my radar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat Makefile

# Make variable (recommended)
x := $(shell bash -c 'echo $$((255 & 2\#11110000))')
$(info [$x])

# Shell variable (not recommended)
a:
    x=`bash -c 'echo $$((255 & 2#11110000))'`; echo $$x
```

Giving

```
$ make
[240]
x=`bash -c 'echo $((255 & 2#11110000))'`; echo $x
240
```

Don't forget that `#` introduces a comment in a makefile!

I recommend using *make* facilities rather than *shell* facilities wherever possible. It usually turns out to be cleaner. (As @ensc says, I do — I use *bash* everywhere in my makefiles :-).)

Comment: Thanks for also mentioning the `#`. It's a pity that `make` variables don't work within targets, though, but only on top-level.

Comment: @ShiDoiSi Eh? Make variables work in every part of a makefile, both targets and recipes. You do have fine control using them.

Comment: Hm, then I'm still doing something wrong: the line `z := $(shell bash -c 'echo $$((255 & 2#11110000))')` in a target yields `gmake: z: Command not found`.

Comment: The `z := …` syntax is _make_, not _bash_. Looks like you have a tab character before the `z`, so that _make_ thinks the line is part of a recipe. Recipes are executed by the shell.

Answer (score 4):

add

```
SHELL = bash
```

to the makefile

Comment: Very interesting, forgot to check where `/bin/sh` points to, indeed. But `dash` should also support arith expansion, though?

Comment: No.  dash is a minimalist implementation of the POSIX standard for the `sh` (shell) utility.  It doesn't provide hardly any extensions to the standard.  This is a good thing as it makes it much more likely that your script will work on systems where `/bin/sh` is not bash.  Bash on the other hand has a very large number of extra features that don't appear in the standard.  Extended arithmetic is one of those features.