# what is the rule file matching of command `rm` in makefile?

Tags: shell, makefile

I was required to run a makefile on mint, I input the option 'clean' about:

```
clean:
<tab> rm -f test_{a,b}.o
```

I type this order in shells `rm -f test_{a,b}.o`, and it do delete the file `test_a.o` and `test_b.o`, but it doesn't work on Mint OS, but it work on CentOS7.

I want to find the reason for this problem. now I use `rm -f test_a.o test_b.o` instead temporarily.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use Bash syntax in Makefile targets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589276/how-can-i-use-bash-syntax-in-makefile-targets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the shell: brace expansion is supported by Bash, but for example not by dash, which is the default `/bin/sh` shell on Ubuntu; and `/bin/sh` is the default shell in Makefiles. You could switch the shell used in the Makefile with

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
```

Comment: On a Mint machine, I tried the order in the command window, it success. and then use `make clean` in the same window, it failed. so the shell used by `make`  is different from its parent bash?

Comment: Your answer is right. I open a shell on Mint, then `echo $SHELL` it is `/bin/bash`; and I write in makefile with `echo $(SHELL)`, it is `/bin/sh`; what a error..

Comment: It would be a complete disaster for portability, if make used whatever random shell the user who typed `make` happened to be using.  It always uses `/bin/sh`.  The value of the `$SHELL` environment variable in the environment of the person who invoked make is irrelevant.